# How to achieve high quality cropped images from canvas?

Tags: image, canvas, crop

I am desperately searching for a good cropping tool. There are a bunch out there, for example:

[Croppic](http://www.croppic.net/)

[Cropit](http://scottcheng.github.io/cropit/)

[Jcrop](http://jcrop.org/)

The most important thing that I am trying to find is a cropping tool, that crops images without making the cropped image low in resolution. You can hack this by using the canvas tag by resizing the image. This way the image itself stays native, only the representation is smaller.
[DarkroomJS](https://mattketmo.github.io/darkroomjs/) was also something near the solution, but, unfortunately, the downloaded demo did not work. I'll try to figure out whats wrong. Does someone know some great alternatives, or how to get the cropped images in...let's say "native" resolution?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: They all do return the native resolution of the images, minus the pixels cropped, so I am a little confused about what you mean. Could you supply an example image showing the problem, and an image of what you expect the result to be so we can see what the problem is.

Comment: Hi Blind! Thanks for the comment. There was an issue back [in Jcrop](http://deepliquid.com/content/Jcrop.html). I am using cropit now. What I meant is, that the cropped image depends on the size of the 'image-preview' window. If I have a large picture, say 1920x1080px, I want to crop a selected area and my 'image-preview' window is 40x40px, i will get a 40x40px image, even if the area would be like for e.g. 500x500px. Is there a way to achieve this 500x500px, by having a lot smaller image preview size?

Answer (score 2):

You are relying on the cropping tool to provide an interface for the users. the problem is that the image returned is sized to the interface and not the original image. Rather than me sifting through the various API's to see if they provide some way of controlling this behaviour (I assume at least some of them would) and because it is such a simple procedure I will show how to crop the image manually.

To use JCrop as an example

Jcrop provides various events for cropstart, cropmove, cropend... You can add a listener to listen to these events and keep a copy of the current cropping interface state

```
var currentCrop;    
jQuery('#target').on('cropstart cropmove cropend',function(e,s,crop){
    currentCrop = crop;
}
```

I don't know where you have set the interface size and I am assuming the events return the crop details at the interface scale

```
var interfaceSize = { //you will have to work this out
     w : ?,
     h : ?.
}
```

Your original image

```
var myImage = new Image(); // Assume you know how to load
```

So when the crop button is clicked you can create the new image by scaling the crop details back to the original image size, creating a canvas at the cropped size, drawing the image so that the cropped area is corectly positioned and returning the canvas as is or as a new image.

```
// image = image to crop
// crop = the current cropping region
// interfaceSize = the size of the full image in the interface
// returns a new cropped image at full res
function myCrop(image,crop,interfaceSize){
     var scaleX = image.width / interfaceSize.w; // get x scale
     var scaleY = image.height / interfaceSize.h; // get y scale
     // get full res crop region. rounding to pixels
     var x = Math.round(crop.x * scaleX);
     var y = Math.round(crop.y * scaleY);
     var w = Math.round(crop.w * scaleX);
     var h = Math.round(crop.h * scaleY);
     // Assume crop will never pad
     // create an drawable image
     var croppedImage = document.createElement("canvas");
     croppedImage.width = w;
     croppedImage.height = h;
     var ctx = croppedImage.getContext("2d");
     // draw the image offset so the it is correctly cropped
     ctx.drawImage(image,-x,-y);
     return croppedImage
}
```

You then only need to call this function when the crop button is clicked

```
var croppedImage;
myButtonElement.onclick = function(){
    if(currentCrop !== undefined){ // ensure that there is a selected crop
        croppedImage = myCrop(myImage,currentCrop,interfaceSize);             
    }
}
```

You can convert the image to a dataURL for download, and upload via

```
imageData = croppedImage.toDataURL(mimeType,quality) // quality is optional and only for "image/jpeg" images
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply Blind, really appreciate it. I'll try it out and come back if there is something else I need to know

Comment: Your `myCrop` function works like a charm. I just want to know, how can I use `window.devicePixelRatio` with your function? Currently, on my device, `window.devicePixelRatio` returns `2`. So, the output of `myCrop` function is twice as large as required output